# Getting the JSON result out of an AJAX query

Tags: php, ajax

I am struggling to get the result of my AJAX query being sent correctly to my PHP script (gethint2.php). Was just wondering what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for being tolerant to me, as I am a newbie in AJAX/Javascript :)

If I don't put the condition (if(isset($_POST['controleur'])) ..., it works perfectly well

**Here is my query :**

```
    <script>
    function showHint2(pControleur) {
        var args = '';
        console.log("Coucou show int " + pControleur);
        /*var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            };        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint2.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();*/
        //args = 'controle='+pControleur;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gethint2.php",
        //data: "{" + args + "}",
        data : {controleur: pControleur},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(code_html, statut){ // success est toujours en place, bien sûr !

        },

        error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){

        },

        complete : function(resultat, statut){

        }

        });
    }

    </script>
```

**My gethint2.php file :**

```
<?php require('common.php');
if(isset($_POST['controleur']))
{
    $result = $db->add_news('titles');
}
?>
```

Comment: what is problem here?

Comment: I should be able to interract with my database, it works if I remove the condition if(isset($_POST['pControleur'])) but as long as I've put this line, I'm struggling.

Comment: try `if(isset($_POST['controleur']))`

Comment: I tried thanks same result

Comment: In your web browser check which parameters are getting posted with that http request. Check for that in `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debug your code with add `var_dump($_POST);` before `if(isset($_POST['controleur']))` in your php file, and check the response via your console browser

the answer is (based on comments below) :

remove the following line `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: This is what I got : array(0) {}
No Properties

Comment: pControleur = "chk01"

Comment: please remove the following line `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and you're done!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help. Last question, do you know what I should change to my php to retrieve the initial value (aka 'chk01') sent by the Ajax?

Comment: send it with `$result` as `json`, it's like `$result['title'] = $db->add_news('titles');  $result['initial'] = $_POST['controleur'];` and send it as json format like `json_encode($result)`

Comment: eh? did i misunderstand about your question? give me your example of the result that you want

Comment: This is now what I get in my array (in PHP) : array(1) { ["controleur"]=> string(5) "chk05" }

-> What I would like is to store this 'chk05' in my $result variable.

Comment: `$result = $_POST['controller']`

Comment: Exactly what I was needing. Thanks a lot ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Debug by looking at the output of `var_dump($_POST)` to see the content that's reaching your script. I bet the array index should be `controleur`.

Comment: Thanks. can you explain me, how I can achieve this, please?